# are there alternatives to program in kotlin without android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to app development and have completed some courses in HTML, CSS, and Python. However, I am not confident that I remember all the information. I want to create an app, but I do not want to use Android Studio. Are there any alternatives? I tried using Android Studio, but encountered some problems that I could not understand.

Comment: Android Studio is the easiest way to develop for Android. You can also use IntelliJ IDEA, but there may be a little more setup required. There are other IDEs you can also use, but they will be much harder to get set up to work correctly, they will have limited options, and you will be relying on third party plugins. You will run into a lot of stumbling blocks with project setup that are hard to find help with because almost everyone uses Android Studio or IntelliJ.

Comment: Let me get you better so do you code only in Python?

Comment: As @Tenfour04 has stated Android Studio is by far the easiest. However, if you run into a problem your posting on a forum that is designed to somewhat help you. Yes Stack Overflow is full of flaggers and if your like me and get flagged to where you can't ask anymore questions because there is no answer, there are times you can get help. But if Stack Overflow thinks your question is stupid to them but it's not for you. I would ask it anyway and if you get banned from asking questions move to another forum that puts developers wanting to learn first. This site has went downhill in the last year